# Why `stoutest` is not a valid regular expression?

Tags: regex, perl

From [`perlop`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html):

> If "/" is the delimiter then the initial m is optional. With the m you can use any pair of non-whitespace characters as delimiters. This is particularly useful for matching path names that contain "/", to avoid LTS (leaning toothpick syndrome). If "?" is the delimiter, then the match-only-once rule of ?PATTERN? applies. If "'" is the delimiter, no interpolation is performed on the PATTERN. When using a character valid in an identifier, whitespace is required after the m.

So I can pick up any letter as a delimiter. Eventually this regex should be fine:

```
stoutest
```

That can be rewritten

```
s/ou/es/
```

However it does not seems to work in Perl. Why?

```
$ perl -e '$_ = qw/ou/; stoutest; print'
ou
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Because Perl can't pick out the operator `s`

[`perldoc perlop`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Regexp-Quote-Like-Operators) says this

> Any non-whitespace delimiter may replace the slashes. Add space after the s when using a character allowed in identifiers.

This program works fine

```
my $s = 'bout';
$s =~ s toutest;
say $s;
```

#### output

```
best
```

Comment: "Because Perl can't pick out the operator s" ...without forbidding functions with names starting with "s".

Answer (score 4):

The substitute operator starts with an `s` identifier, and you code doesn't have one. Gotta use

```
s toutest
```

If it worked the way you think, we couldn't have any operators or subroutines that start with `m`, `s`, `tr`, `q` or `y` since all of them can be followed by any non-whitespace delimiter.

---

Ironically, your very own code proves demonstrates why it can't be the way you think. If it worked the way you think

```
$_ = qw/ou/; stoutest; print
```

wouldn't be equivalent to

```
$_ = qw/ou/; s/ou/es/; print
```

It would be equivalent to

```
$_ = q'/ou/; stoutest; print
```

aka

```
$_ = '/ou/; stoutest; print
```

Answer (score 4):

Because `stoutest`, or any other string of alphanumeric characters, is a single token in the eyes of the Perl parser. Otherwise we couldn't use any barewords that begin with `s` (or `m`, or `q`, or `y`).

This works, though

```
$_ = "ou";
s toutest;
print
```